# Is it possible to call a DbFunction inside my ValueConverter?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a Scalar-Function in the database which I have mapped to EF Core using the `DbFunction` Attribute. I am trying to call this DbFunction inside a value-converter. So I am trying the following inside my DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(e => e.Firstname)
        .HasConversion(e => e, e => GetTranslation());
}

[DbFunction("GetTranslation", "dbo")]
public static string GetTranslation()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Sadly this does not work. The DbFunction will not get called.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Value converters run on the client not the database so your db function wouldn't work there

The only way to accomplish is to replicate the db function code in c# and instead of throwing not implemented you could put that logic in there. And use it then on your value converter, if the function is called on the database it would use the db function from the db if its called locally it will use the c# code